# JS\Jquery - Use easing function on a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, easing, jquery-easing

I have a CSS\JS based gauge with a dial that is animated with a jQuery.easing function.
I want to have a numerical counter that raises with the dial. For this to happen, I'll need to apply the same easing function with the same time on a variable ("animate" a number that's not an attribute)

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Need to see a working example to establish the relationship here. This is far too ambiguous.

Comment: If the dial animation is done with jQuery's .animate() method, you could add a callback to the `step` option that increments the variable with the current value of the animation.

Comment: Kevin - that was exactly what I was looking for.
Thanks :)